# Is it possible to serve only the index.html, or at least not expose the services and components in an angular 2 app?

Tags: node.js, angular, web-deployment

I am close to being ready to deploy to my hosted web server, which is with In-motion Hosting.  They run centos 6.x.  I would like to only serve the index.html file to the browser so as to keep several API keys as private as possible.  I can't seem to track down the file that serves or routes to the index.html file and get the "Cannot Get /" error when its not at the same level as the app directory.  Is there a way to keep the app directory out of the public_html folder?  I am using the angular quick-start structure from their github repo.

Thank You

[image]

Comment: Can you show your app structure?

Comment: As it is the entire app is exposed to the browser.  My other option is to not use angular and make all API calls from node.js but then what's the point of Angular being able to do it?  Thank You again.